# Angularjs : Print object from control to view with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to build new APP with `ionic framework` and `Angularjs`.

Now my problem is i cannot show the result from controller to view. I try open `console.log(allposts);`  in my browser ans we show the result good.

But in view its not show any thing

allpost.html

```
<dive class="item itemfull" ng-repeat="post in allpost">
<div class="item item-body">
<div>{{ post.title }}
<div class="title-news"><div class="title" ng-bind-html="post.content"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the controller

```
myApp.controller('allpost', function($scope , $http , $stateParams , Allposts) {
        var id = $stateParams.id;
        $scope.post = Allposts.GetAllposts(id);
    });

myApp.factory('Allposts',['$http', '$q',function($http,$q){
                var allposts = [];
                var pages = null;
                return {

                GetAllposts: function (id) {
                    return $http.get("http://kotshgfx.info/azkarserv/?json=get_category_posts&id="+id+"&status=publish",{params: null}).then(function (response) {
                       items = response.data.posts;
                        allposts = items;
                        console.log(allposts); 
                        return items;
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                    });
                }
                }
        }]);
```

Where is error ?

Comment: check in your $scope.post whether all posts are coming or not by using `console.log($scope.post)`

Comment: try to change the code like this in controller $scope.allpost = Allposts.GetAllposts(id);

Comment: its look like [http://postimg.org/image/uip34gns9/](http://postimg.org/image/uip34gns9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the code like this in controller and factory in js files

```
.controller('allpost', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, Allposts) {
    var id = $stateParams.id;
    Allposts.GetAllposts(id).then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.allPosts = response.data.posts;
        });

})

.factory('Allposts', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return {

        GetAllposts: function (id) {
            return $http.get("http://kotshgfx.info/azkarserv/?json=get_category_posts&id=" +
                id + "&status=publish");

        }
    }
}]);
```

the html file

```
 <div class="item itemfull" ng-repeat="post in allPosts">
        <div class="item item-body">
            <div>{{ post.title }}
                <div class="title-news">
                    <div class="title" ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works for my test

[image: Result of test]

Comment: Try the code again and tell me if you got any problem!

Comment: nice ,,, its work no thank you .. can you explain what do ?!

Comment: Promise returned from $http can not be binded directly, we use promises as a sort of 'callback handle' - do something asynchronous in a service, return a promise, and when the asynchronous work is done, the promise's then function is triggered. check some tutorial on how to use Promises and Angular.